# How to Mock class variable

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, moq, xunit

I am writing test cases using xUnit and Moq.

Currently I am writing test case for Telemetry class.

```
 public  class TelemetryClientMock : ITelemetryClientMock
    {
       public string key { get; set; } //I want to mock key variable.
        private TelemetryClient telemetry;  
        public TelemetryClientMock( )
        {
            telemetry = new TelemetryClient() { InstrumentationKey = key };
        }



        public void TrackException(Exception exceptionInstance, IDictionary<string, string> properties = null)
        {

              telemetry.TrackException(exceptionInstance, properties);
        }

        public void TrackEvent(string eventLog)
        {
            telemetry.TrackEvent(eventLog);
        }

    }
```

In Test class how can I mock, key variable.I used to write below code for mocking method.

```
          [Fact]
            public void TrackException_Success()
            {
                Exception ex=null;
                IDictionary<string, string> dict = null;
               var reader = new Mock<ITelemetryClientMock>();
                var mockTelemetryClient = new Mock<ITelemetryClientMock>();
//mocking method below
                mockTelemetryClient
                    .Setup(data => data.TrackException(It.IsAny<Exception>(), It.IsAny<IDictionary<string, string>>()));
                this._iAppTelemetry = new AppTelemetry(mockTelemetryClient.Object);
                this._iAppTelemetry.TrackException(ex,dict);
            }
```

How can I mock variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using `Setup`, `SetupProperty`, `SetupGet`, depending on what you want:

```cs
mockTelemetryClient.Setup(x => x.key).Returns("foo");
```

or

```cs
mockTelemetryClient.SetupProperty(x => x.key, "foo");
```

or

```cs
mockTelemetryClient.SetupGet(x => x.key).Returns("foo");
```

As [Alves RC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5342210/alves-rc) pointed out, it is assumed that `key` property exists in `ITelemetryClientMock` interface.

Comment: Your answer is correct but I think you could add the following to make sure whatever they're attempting to Mock is "Mockable":

"In order to Moq to be able to Mock anything it should be either an `Interface` or a `virtual` Property"